# Instantiation of multi architecture vhdl enity in verilog testbench

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I have to develop a verilog tb for a design in vhdl. The design has multiple entities each entity has multiple architectures. I want to develop a verilog wrapper around each entity and then use that wrapper to communicate with the test bench. As the entity has different architecture for different testcase, with this approach each testcase has to be compile separately. Is there a better way of doing this ?? Any suggestions for uvm implementation ?

Comment: Expecting Verilog tools to understand VHDL properly may be asking a bit much. If you wrap all the VHDL in a single-entity-single-arch (VHDL) wrapper, things may go more smoothly. Also any limitations and issues are likely to be highly tool dependent; it may be worth naming the tools you have at hand.

Comment: i am using cadence incisive simulator irun for compiling and elaborating. Can you elaborate a little regarding single-entity-single-arch (VHDL) wrapper ?

Comment: Only this : mixing Verilog models in a VHDL testbench. One tool (different tool : Xilinx ISE simulator) would not let me instantiate two instances of the same Verilog module (DDR DRAM) in a testbench so I had to sim with a single memory. Where the "features" are in your tools I can't tell, but the simpler your VHDL interface is, the less likely you are to hit them. I suppose a better question is : do you really need Verilog?

Answer (score 0):

This is simulator-specific. For ModelSim, for example, your Verilog TB can instantiate an entity, an entity/architecture pair, or a configuration (which is what you want). I'd be very surprised if incisive can't do this - check your manuals.